# Java rxtx code to connect to rfcomm0 is not working

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino, rxtx, rfcomm

I have successfully connected my arduino uno R3 with bluetooth mate module and am able to send data to my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 via bluetooth. (using serial port protocol). The data is received on rfcomm0.

The following code displays the received data : `sudo screen /dev/rfcomm0`

Now I am facing problems in reading this data in a java program. I have referred the code from http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java. This uses the rxtx library to access the serial port.

Here is the code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM3", // Windows
//          "/dev/ttyACM0" // Ubuntu
            "/dev/rfcomm0" // Ubuntu Bluetooth
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 10 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Started");
        t.start();
        t.join();
        main.close();
        System.out.println("Stopped");
    }
}
```

This program compiles seccessfully but when executes displays : `"Could not find COM port."`

Note : This code works perfectly when reading data from usb port /dev/ttyACM0. The problem arises when i try to read data from bluetooth port /dev/rfcomm0.

So basically I need a java program to read from rfcomm0 port. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `System.out.println(currPortId.getName());` call after the `CommPortIdentifier currPortId = ...` line to see what port IDs are being found?

Comment: @angelatlarge : 
`System.out.println(currPortId.getName());` returned `/dev/ttyACM0`
hmm... I have connected my arduino to that port for power it up... looks like that is interfering with the bluetooth serial port rfcomm0. Let me power the arduino from other source and try it out.

Comment: OK, so to state the obvious, it sounds like Java is not finding your `/dev/rfcomm0` port. However, you said that `sudo screen /dev/rfcomm0` was working, which suggests that this is a Java/JVM-specific issue?

Comment: turns out the `screen` command worked because of `sudo`... The java program couldnt read from rfcomm0 because it didnt have the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @angelatlarge for his suggestion.

The problem was that the java program did not have the permission to access `/dev/rfcomm0`.

Command to provide permission : `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/rfcomm0`

So giving the permission to `/dev/rfcomm0` solved the problem for me.
Now the java program can read the data from the rfcomm0 port.

Comment: Maybe once the time period passes accept your own answer so that people know that the issue is resolved.  Glad you got it working!  Though now that I think about it, you shouldn't need to protect `/dev/ttyACM0` with permissions, right?  If you comment it out as an "acceptable" port name in your code, your java code should never open it, right?

Comment: Even though I had commented `/dev/ttyACM0` out in the java program the `System.out.println(currPortId.getName());` did display it for some reason! Check out the pic : < http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/12432443/img/12432443.png > ...

Comment: No, it should display, we expected that: the print statement was above the `if`. But it should not make it past the `if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {` : meaning you shouldn't have to restrict access to it.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Right! So the only change required was for the permission of `/dev/rfcomm0`. Tried it with that and it worked. Have changed my answer. Thanx

Comment: Cool. Maybe go ahead and accept your answer after you can (there is a waiting period) so that people know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: same problem occurs to me but changing permission of rfcomm0 didn't work for me