# Python script working with Arduino won't read data correct

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, temperature

I've got a problem with my Python script. It's working but something is wrong. I'm newbie in Python so I can't find any solution :(

My script is connecting via pySerial to Arduino board, and read temperature data. It's connecting fine but data shown in terminal or save in TXT file (with Cron) is wrong:

```
2013-03-16 13:40:01 166.8
2013-03-16 13:41:02 1617.
```

where it should be:

```
2013-03-16 13:40:01 16.68
2013-03-16 13:41:02 16.17
```

My Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# pytemp.py

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout=10)
read = ser.read(5)
comp = read.split()
ser.close();
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), comp[0]
```

I'm using Python3.3, with pySerial 2.6. In oryginal version there was:

```
read = ser.readline(eol=/r)
```

but as far as I know in 2.5+ eol command is not working anymore. I have no idea how to edit my script to print data correct all the time.

Comment: Can you read Arduino data from `/dev/ttyACM0` _without_ Python?  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450419/java-rxtx-code-to-connect-to-rfcomm0-is-not-working) is a similar-looking problem in Java.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `read` (before splitting)?

Comment: Yes I can read Arduino data with screen /dev/ttyACM0. And it shows normal, correct nubers, all the time for example 21.89. So there is only problem with my python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline), the eol parameter is indeed no longer supported when using Python version 2.6 of higher.

Please disregard my previous advice to use `FileLike`. That isn't using in python 2.6+ either!

How you have to handle the data depends on *how the data looks*. Since you haven't given us an example of the raw data, I'll be using the format from [this page](http://lallafa.de/blog/2012/11/build-an-arduino-based-temperature-logger/) as an example.

The format of the data in the abovementioned example is:

```
t: 2012.11.18 19:39:03 50A93957 +024.50 0189
t: 2012.11.18 19:39:13 50A93961 +024.50 0189
t: 2012.11.18 19:39:23 50A9396B +024.50 0188
```

Each line has the following columns:

- date and time
- raw date and time in hex
- temperature value in degree celsuis
- raw temperature value in hex

You will notice that each measurement starts with a 't:', and has six items separated by spaces. So in this case I would run a loop that works like this:

```
import serial
import time

buffer = bytes()
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout=10)
while buffer.count('t:') < 2:
    buffer += ser.read(30)
ser.close();
# Now we have at least one complete datum. Isolate it.
start = buffer.index('t:')
end = buffer.index('t:', start+1)
items = buffer[start:end].strip().split()
print items[1], items[2], items[4]
```

An example. Realize that you might begin reading in the middle of a line of data. You cannot assume you start reading at the beginning of a line.

```
In [23]: buffer = '39:03 50A9\r\nt: 2012.11.18 19:39:13 50A93961 +024.50 0189\r\nt: 2012.11.18 19:39:23 50A9396B +024.50 0188'
```

Let's check how many 't:''s we can find. (You could also search for '\r\n' instead. All that matters is that you have something to delimiter lines with)

```
In [24]: buffer.count('t:')
Out[24]: 2
```

Since we have two delimiters, we have at least one data point. Let's isolate the complete data point.

```
In [25]: buffer.index('t:')
Out[25]: 12

In [26]: buffer.index('t:', 12+1)
Out[26]: 58
```

This is what we want to see. A complete data point:

```
In [27]: buffer[12:58+1].strip().split()
Out[27]: ['t:', '2012.11.18', '19:39:13', '50A93961', '+024.50', '0189', 't']

In [28]: items = buffer[12:59].strip().split()

In [29]: print items[1], items[2], items[4]
2012.11.18 19:39:13 +024.50
```

Comment: Something is wrong. My new code is: ser = serial.Filelike('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout=10) and I'm getting error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Filelike'

Comment: You should use a capital L in FileLike.